# integrating java web application activiti bpmn

Tags: activiti, bpmn

My is requirement is I will design the simple leave application in java using eclipse IDE in JSP/servlet without using activiti explorer that not activiti form or UI.

MY Leave app UI consist of two fields name and number of leave user apply and submit button , once I hit on the submit button it should to go admin that is assignee whom it is assigned ,When I login as the admin ,I should see the leave request in my queue. I am not at all using activiti UI from . I dont have any idea how to start with requirement . Because my UI (which is designed outside the activiti , not using activiti UI forms) should talk to activiti and processed to next step or should move to next step for whom it is assigned , when the assignee login he should see that request in his queue. If you have any sample example you provide the link. It would be great , if you can help on this.

Actually i am aware of basic components of activiti but at high level not able to visualise how bpmn workflow get integrated with web application.

Comment: You can think Activiti as a simple library. In your leave form the submit action will invoke some controller where you use APIs like startProcessBy xxx. In some other for you use the query apis in order to retrieve a list of pending tasks (eg: leave approval) and show them to the user.  A good start point for a project is start.spring.io. select the "full version" and create a project with web, jpa, h2 and Activiti support.

Comment: Complementing my previous comment, I think you should check the following blog article that shows you pretty much you need to start your project: https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot